# Simplifying nested If statements

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

Consider :

```
list = {100,102,103,99,106,107,104,112}
```

I want to consider, extract only the "big moves" of that time series. In this case the moves bigger then 5 from the moving point of reference.

The pseudo code would go as such :

Let's assume you have the data `x(t)` for `t=1` to `T`,

You start from the first data point, `z(1) = x(1)`

```
if abs(x(2)-z(1))> delta, 
    z(2)= x(2), 
elseif abs(x(3)-z(1))> delta, 
    z(2)= x(3), 
elseif abs(x(4)-z(1))> delta, 
    z(2)= x(4),    
    if abs(x(5)-z(2))> delta, 
        z(3)= x(5), 
    elseif abs(x(6)-z(2))>delta, 
        z(3)= x(6),
        if abs(x(7)-z(3))>delta, 
            z(4)=x(7)
        endif
    endif
endif
```

I tried to write it with an `If` statement, but I don't know when my test is going to pass thus, how many `If`s to nest.

```
If[Abs[list[[2]]-list[[1]]]>5,
   list[[2]],
             If[Abs[list[[3]]-list[[1]]>5,
             list[[3]]....
```

Here this process will stop at `list[[5]]` with `Abs[list[[5]]-list[[1]]=6`

At this point, `list[[5]]` becomes my new point of reference :

```
 If[Abs[list[[6]]-list[[5]]]>5,
     list[[6]],
              If[Abs[list[[7]]-list[[5]]>5,
             list[[7]]....
```

So my desired output is the following :

```
{100,106,112}
```

I am pretty sure, this type of operation has a name but I don't know it. It felt like a `While[]` or `For[]` but I can`t figure it out. Please let me know how to improve the question.

Comment: You meant "You start from the first data point, z(1) = x(1)"?

Comment: @Rojo, Yes ! Thank you, Edited.

Comment: 500, apparently I misunderstood your question, so please disregard my answers for the time being.  I'll leave them for reference.  I am too tired to fix it now.

Comment: 500, just FYI, you're getting you've been using backquotes (`) instead of an apostrophe (') in contractions.  For example "don`t" instead of "don't", which causes problems with the formatting of your posts.

Comment: This reminds me of things like `KagiChart` and `RenkoChart` which have similar behavior.  It's not easy to clearly and concisely describe them either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In contrast to the very fast methods presented, let me give you a maybe more easy to understand solution (while this in the eye of the beholder). Basically it's sort of the way I would implement it in Haskell.

Assume you want to solve your problem step by step and in each step you have your data in the form `{res, in}` where `res` is your current solution and `in` is the rest of the input which needs to be processed. The initial situation is that the list `res` contains your first element and `in` contains the rest of the input. Let's go through the two possible situations:

- Since `res` is your current output, you always want to compare the last element of this with the first element of your `in` list. When the absolute difference is larger then 5, you want to append this first element of `in` to your `res` list.
- In all other cases, you just want to throw away the first element of `in` and leave `res` untouched.

You want to iterate this as long as there are elements in your input. Thats all, and you can write it directly down:

```
step[{res_, in_}] := {Append[res, First[in]], Rest[in]} /; 
  Abs[Last[res] - First[in]] > 5;

step[{res_, in_}] := {res, Rest[in]};

NestWhile[step, {{100}, {102, 103, 99, 106, 107, 104, 112}}, 
 Length[Last[#]] > 0 &]

(* {{100, 106, 112}, {}} *)
```

You see that after your input list is empty, you have collected your result.

Answer (score 8):

Something along these lines could work:

```
Reap[
  Sow[ z = list[[1]] ];
  Scan[If[Abs[# - z] > delta, Sow[z = #]] &, list]
][[2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 7):

I favor `Fold` over `Scan`.  I find it faster, and it does without an additional variable.

```
Reap[
  Fold[If[Abs[#2 - #] > delta, Sow[#2], #] &, Infinity, list];
][[2, 1]]
```

---

500 asked:

> How could I now store as a sublist every element skipped in between
>   the z points in addition to the the z point themselves.  I would like
>   to have the list of the coordinates that do not pass the test, but
>   sublists for each group of point skipped in between two `Sow[]`.

This is the cleanest method I could think of:

```
list = {100, 102, 103, 99, 106, 107, 104, 107, 112};

idx =
  Reap[i = 0;
    Fold[If[++i; Abs[#2 - #] > delta, Sow[i]; #2, #] &, Infinity, list];
  ][[2, 1]];

MapThread[list[[# ;; #2]] &, {idx, Append[Rest@idx - 1, -1]}]
```

> ```
> {{100, 102, 103, 99}, {106, 107, 104, 107}, {112}}
> ```

The output is a list of sublists, each starting with a "z point" and continuing with intervening elements before the next point.

Comment: @500 I just added a much faster, if admittedly more specific answer.

Comment: This doesn't give the answer I expect for `{100, 102, 103, 99, 106, 107, 104, 107, 112}`.

Comment: @Brett Since two notes of incorrect output have been made I perhaps didn't understand the question.  What output do you expect for that list?

Comment: Btw, I had written a similar solution and deleted it in a panick attack. It had a bug however not sowing the first element, that you neatly dealt with with that Infinity. +1 for the Infinity, hehe

Comment: I expect `{100, 106, 112}`.  See the responses from @halirutan and @Rojo on your other answer.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of Reap and Sow just when I need it !

Comment: @Rojo please check both functions on this page to see if they now work.

Comment: I am using your solution as you probably saw in my last question. Now I have a little question on this : How could I now store as sublist avery elements skipped in between the z points in addition to the the z point themselves ? I am sorry i am definitely not agile with reap and sow[] yet.

Comment: @500 do you mean a separate list for each `z` point, or one big list for all elements that are not explicit `z` points?

Comment: @Mr Wizard, thank you for your attention. I would like to have the list of the coordinates that do not pass the test. But sublists for each group of point skipped in between two Sow[] ?

Comment: @500 please see (and test) my updated answer.

Comment: @Mr, thank you, I will test later today !

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly faster version based on `FoldList` and `Split`.

```
Split[
  FoldList[If[Abs[#2 - #] > delta, #2, #] &, Infinity, list]
][[2 ;;, 1]]
```

Comment: I think your first function works not correctly. Can you test the input `{20, 56, 57, 62, 20}`?

Comment: @halirutan Since two notes of incorrect output have been made I perhaps didn't understand the question.  What output do you expect for that list?

Comment: @MrWizard I expect `{20, 56, 62, 20}`. You misunderstood maybe, that after the test for `(56,57)` fails, 56 is kept as *reference element` until a test succeeds.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, this one yes shows you misunderstood. It doesn't do the same as your previous answer. This one only collects those contiguous jumps above delta, but he wants to go dropping values until you get to the delta difference. So if delta=3, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8} should give {0, 4, 8} if I understood

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yeah, they seem to work well if I understood the problem. I was wrong with my comment on the other post the other day, I had a blank and thought Sow as something that returned Null. +1 on this one now

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach, based on a recursive function and pattern matching.

```
MinDifference[list_, d_] := MinDifference[{First[list]}, Rest[list], d]

MinDifference[store_, {}, d_] := store

MinDifference[{store___, s_}, {v_, list___}, d_] /; Abs[v-s] > d := 
   MinDifference[{store, s, v}, {list}, d]

MinDifference[{store___}, {v_, list___}, d_] := 
   MinDifference[{store}, {list}, d]
```

---

```
MinDifference[{100, 102, 103, 99, 106, 107, 104, 112}, 5]
```

> ```
> {100, 106, 112}
> ```

```
MinDifference[{100, 102, 103, 99, 106, 107, 104, 107, 112}, 5]
```

> ```
> {100, 106, 112}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Another yet-another possibility is **`ReplaceRepeated`:**

Define

```
crossings = ({{First[#1]}, #1}) //. 
({a_, {Shortest[b__], e___}} /; (Abs[First@{b} - Last@{b}] > #2) 
 :> {Insert[a, Last@{b}, -1], {Last@{b}, e}}) &
```

Usage:

```
 crossings @@ {list, 5}
```

gives

> {{100, 106, 112}, {112}}

the first part of which gives the desired result:

```
 crossings @@ {list, 5} //First
 (* ==> {{100, 106, 112} *)
```

An alternative is using  **`ReplaceAll`** in combination with  **`FixedPointList`**:

```
 crossingList[list_, delta_] := 
 First /@ Most@
 FixedPointList[#1 /. ({Shortest[a__], b___} /; 
 (Abs[First@{a} - Last@{a}] > delta) 
 :> {Last@{a}, b}) &, list]
```