# Conditional Data Selection, efficiency

Tags: list-manipulation, data-structures

Building up on the solution proposed here : [Simplifying nested If statements](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/simplifying-nested-if-statements)

You can find [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20775208/Sparrow/7744cca1699d9a52d823aab8f36c5283/allGazes.dat.gz) the data set : allGazes.dat

```
allGazesX = 
 Uncompress@
   Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "allGazes.dat.gz"}], 
    "String"];
```

I need to filter large data set and believe I lack an efficient method to do so. The purpose here is to filter given the `EuclideanDistance[]` between gazes. Below is what I am using currently :

This is what i am using currently :

```
GZ[delta_] := ParallelTable[
              Table[
                    Reap[z = allGazesX[[subNO, dispNo, 1, ;; 2]];Sow[z];
                    Scan[
                         If[
                            EuclideanDistance[#, z] > delta,
                            z = #;Sow[z]] &,
                            allGazesX[[subNO, dispNo, All, ;; 2]]]][[2, 1]],

              {dispNo, Range[Length[allGazesX[[subNO]]]]}],
              {subNO, Range[5]}];
```

Comment: Might I ask why you aren't using `ParallelTable` for both `dispNo` and `subNO`?

Comment: Not having actual data, I'm not exactly sure what this is doing. But it looks like it might possibly benefit from use of single-argument Nearest[].

Comment: @rcollyer, If you do, I believe you get an error message saying you can`t have nested ParallelTable[]

Comment: Both `Table` and `ParallelTable` accept multiple iterator arguments, or should. So, you could write `ParallelTable[..., {subNO, ...}, {dispNo, ...}]` instead of nesting the second `Table` inside. Note, `dispNo` has to go after `subNO` which it depends on. Does that clarify what I was asking? Or, do you still get an error message?

Comment: @rcollyer I think, using `Table` inside `ParallelTable` may make sense, if you want to force certain (coarse) granularity of your computations.

Comment: @Daniel Can you tell us how `Nearest` works?  I timed it the other day, and the NearestFunction seemed to run in linear time in the number of points used to build it, both for 1D and 2D data with Euclidean distance.  However, occasionally I got some inconsistent timings where the first run of the NearestFunction was slow, but the subsequent ones were fast.  I couldn't reproduce this for large data though.  Surely it must have better than linear complexity, but a naive measurement shows linear.  Note I am talking about the timings for the NearestFunction, not Nearest.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I agree. I was just curious as to why he made that choice.

Comment: @Szabolcs I really should know the answer but I'm not recalling all details. For Euclidean distance and machine precision it should be substantially faster for lookup, approaching log(n) if you want some smallish constant number of nearby neighbors to a given value. There is a degradation with dimension but of course in 1 or 2 D this is not relevant.

Comment: @Szabolcs I should also have said something about internals. Nearest uses an octree behind the scenes. So lookup tends to be fast. Or should be. If you are seeing discrepant behavior you might consider sending a bug report (can send to me, if you like).

Comment: @Daniel, Do you think Nearest would be faster in my case > I have never used that function yet !

Comment: @500 Possibly Nearest would be useful (as in fast). As I said though, I'm not exactly sure what it is you arwe doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Apparently, I have misunderstood the problem. Here is the solution which, for smaller tests, produces the results identical to the original one:

```
getDistantPoints = 
  Compile[{{pts, _Real, 2}, {delta, _Real}},
     Module[{res = Table[{0., 0.}, {Length[pts]}], ctr = 1},
        res[[1]] = pts[[1]];
        Do[
          If[Norm[pts[[i]] - res[[ctr]]] > delta, 
            res[[++ctr]] = pts[[i]]
          ], 
          {i, Length[pts]}];
        Take[res, ctr]],
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]


Clear[GZFastAlt];
GZFastAlt[delta_, data_] :=
  Module[{ldata = data},
     ParallelTable[
       Table[
          getDistantPoints[ldata [[subNO, dispNo, All, ;; 2]], delta],
          {dispNo, Range[Length[ldata [[subNO]]]]}
       ], {subNO, Range[5]}]];
```

and runs in about 2 seconds on my 6 cores:

```
(res = GZFastAlt[0.1,allGazesX]);//AbsoluteTiming
{2.2451172,Null}
```

**END EDIT**

As a bonus, this keeps things packed, which is a big deal for your data - even in packed form, the computation consumes quite a bit of memory.

Comment: Are these identical? In the original, the value of z is a moving target, so to speak.

Comment: @Daniel Good point! I thought `z` was only used as a recording device, and did not think that it can be important. Actually, `z` being a moving target makes more sense. Will think of a modification for this case, and hopefully updates soon.

Comment: @Daniel Ok, fixed (hopefully). Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: You're welcome. As regards things that get spotted, I'm just glad it was a wandering 'z and not a hungry leopard. [Exit stage left, ducking rotting vegetables from audience.]

Comment: @Daniel That assumes the audience was well-prepared, and actually expecting the failure :)