# Partitioning a list when the cumulative sum exceeds 1

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning

I have a long list of say 1 million Uniform(0,1) random numbers, such as:

```
 dat = {0.71, 0.685, 0.16, 0.82, 0.73, 0.44, 0.89, 0.02, 0.47, 0.65}
```

I want to partition this list whenever the cumulative sum exceeds 1. For the above data, the desired output would be:

> {{0.71, 0.685}, {0.16, 0.82, 0.73}, {0.44, 0.89}, {0.02, 0.47, 0.65}}

I was trying to find a neat way to do this efficiently with `Split` combined with say `Accumulate` or `FoldList` or `Total`, but my attempts with `Split` have not been fruitful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you most concerned with "a neat way" or absolute performance?  I posted the cleanest method I could think of but I doubt it will perform as well as a simple procedural loop in `Compile`.

Comment: Related: [(2304)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2304/121), [(102900)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102900/121)

Comment: I like clean methods - and yours is super! Thanks. On testing, it is not as fast as it looks ... which may be because of the `AddTo` (which, in the past, at least, was a slow mma function). Given `dat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^6];`, your method takes about 1.5 seconds on my Mac ... I was hoping to find something about 3 to 5 times faster.

Comment: I just updated my answer with one that's a bit faster, but IMHO not enough faster to justify the ugliness. ;^)  I shall try to improve it further.

Comment: Seems like a borderline dupe of [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3908/getting-lengths-of-sublists-that-sum-to-more-than-one) - the only missing step from there to this one in to use ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` or Mr. Wizard's `dynP` on the result. In any case, very strongly related.

Comment: @Leonid Wow, that is closely related, and I seem to have forgotten it despite voting for your answer.  If I had remembered that question when I first saw this one I would probably have closed it without even trying to answer.  Now however my `Split` method would be out of place there which makes it difficult for me to be happy about a close.  So I'm not sure what to do or which hat to wear (moderator or user).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This seems to be a rare case where the question is as much a dupe as it is not, in terms of making this decision. As of now, I think we should probably keep this quuestion, but somehow make a reference to that one very visible, so that whoever comes here, will also see that one.

Comment: @wolfies Thanks for the Accept. :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
dat = {0.71, 0.685, 0.16, 0.82, 0.73, 0.44, 0.89, 0.02, 0.47, 0.65};

Module[{t = 0},
  Split[dat, (t += #) <= 1 || (t = 0) &]
]
```

> ```
> {{0.71, 0.685}, {0.16, 0.82, 0.73}, {0.44, 0.89}, {0.02, 0.47, 0.65}}
> ```

[Credit to Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7820/121) for getting me to think about using [`Or`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html) in applications like this.

---

### Performance

I decided to make an attempt at a higher performing solution at the cost of elegance and clarity.

```
f2[dat_List] := Module[{bin, lns},
   bin = 1 - Unitize @ FoldList[If[# <= 1`, #, 0`] & @ +## &, dat]; 
   lns = SparseArray[bin]["AdjacencyLists"] ~Prepend~ 0 // Differences;
   Internal`PartitionRagged[dat,
      If[# > 0, Append[lns, #], lns] &[Length @ dat - Tr @ lns]
   ]
 ]
```

And a second try at performance using [Szabolcs's inversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/121):

```
f3[dat_List] :=
  Module[{bin},
    bin = 1 - Unitize @ FoldList[If[# <= 1`, #, 0`] & @ +## &, dat];
    bin = Reverse @ Accumulate @ Reverse @ bin;
    dat[[#]] & /@ GatherBy[Range @ Length @ dat, bin[[#]] &]
  ]
```

Using [`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html) seems natural here but it tested slower than [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html).

*Modified October 2018 to use [Carl Woll's `GatherByList`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158637/121):*

```
GatherByList[list_, representatives_] := Module[{func},
    func /: Map[func, _] := representatives;
    GatherBy[list, func]
]

f4[dat_List] :=
  Module[{bin},
    bin = 1 - Unitize @ FoldList[If[# <= 1`, #, 0`] & @ +## &, dat];
    bin = Reverse @ Accumulate @ Reverse @ bin;
    GatherByList[dat, bin]
  ]
```

The other functions to compare:

```
f1[dat_List] := Module[{t = 0}, Split[dat, (t += #) <= 1 || (t = 0) &]]

fqwerty[dat_List] :=
  Module[{f},
    f[x_, y_] := Module[{new}, If[Total[new = Append[x, y]] >= 1, Sow[new]; {}, new]];
    Reap[Fold[f, {}, dat]][[2, 1]]
  ]

fAlgohi[dat_List] :=
 Module[{i = 0, r},
  Split[dat, (If[r, , i = 0]; i += #; r = i <= 1) &]
 ]
```

And a single point benchmark using "a long list of say 1 million Uniform(0,1) random numbers:"

```
SeedRandom[0]
test = RandomReal[1, 1*^6];

fqwerty[test] // Length // RepeatedTiming
fAlgohi[test] // Length // RepeatedTiming
f1[test]      // Length // RepeatedTiming
f2[test]      // Length // RepeatedTiming
f3[test]      // Length // RepeatedTiming
f4[test]      // Length // RepeatedTiming
main1[test]   // Length // RepeatedTiming    (* from LLlAMnYP's answer *)
```

> ```
> {6.54, 368130}
>
> {1.59, 368131}
>
> {1.29, 368131}
>
> {0.474, 368131}
>
> {0.8499, 368131}
>
> {0.4921, 368131}
>
> {0.2622, 368131}
> ```

I note that qwerty's solution has one less sublist in the output because he does not include the final trailing elements if they do not exceed one.  I do not know which behavior is desired.

Comment: +1, I was working on it and got another version of similar idea. `i=0; Split[dat, (If[r, , i = 0]; i += #1; r = i < 1) &]`

Comment: +1, good stuff. But. I hesitate to vote for closing, but it seems a borderline dupe of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3908/getting-lengths-of-sublists-that-sum-to-more-than-one). What do you think?

Answer (score 11):

Here's my take at making a function as fast as possible.

```
main = Module[{idxs = sub[Accumulate@#]}, 
    Internal`PartitionRagged[#, idxs]] &;
sub = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{i, l = Length[list], ref = 1., bag = Internal`Bag[{0}]},
    For[i = 1, i <= l, i++,
     If[list[[i]] >= ref || i == l, Internal`StuffBag[bag, i]; 
      ref = list[[i]] + 1.;]
     ];
    Differences[Internal`BagPart[bag, All]]
    ]];
```

It's maybe 5% faster than Mr. Wizards `f2` function, but the real bottleneck is `PartitionRagged` which takes about 80-85% of the time. I suppose, there's not much to gain from compiling, and what's needed, is a fast ragged partition routine. `Part` is compilable, however `Compile` does not like to return ragged arrays.

**EDIT**
This got me thinking about proper treatment of ragged arrays. While I didn't come up with any proper solution, I did manage to construct a compilable function, that creates a *rectangular* array with the desired output, but padded to the right with zeros.

```
main1 = Function[{list}, 
   Block[{sum = Accumulate[list]}, sub2[sub1[sum], list]]];
sub1 = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{i, l = Length[list], ref = 1., bag = Internal`Bag[{0}], 
     idxs},
    For[i = 1, i <= l, i++,
     If[list[[i]] >= ref || i == l, Internal`StuffBag[bag, i]; 
      ref = list[[i]] + 1.;]
     ];
    idxs = Internal`BagPart[bag, All];
    {Most[idxs] + 1, Rest[idxs], Differences[idxs]} // Transpose
    ]];
sub2 = Compile[{{idxs, _Integer, 2}, {list, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{result = 
      ConstantArray[0., {Length[idxs], Max[idxs[[All, 3]]]}], i},
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[idxs], i++,
     result[[i, ;; idxs[[i, 3]]]] = 
      list[[idxs[[i, 1]] ;; idxs[[i, 2]]]]];
    result]];
```

This is about 30% faster than the previous result. One might assume, that if we're talking about running totals, more often than not we're looking at non-negative numbers, so padding with zeros (or maybe a large negative number) will not lead to ambiguity.

Comment: I quickly realized that ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` was a bottleneck.  I then realized the foolishness of my earlier comment about "a simple procedural loop in Compile" when I tried to get around it, for the reason you mention.

Answer (score 9):

`` Internal`PartitionRagged `` uses `Accumulate` internally to generate a list of positions from the sub-list lengths, then `MapThread` and `Take` to extract the corresponding elements from the array. You can check the internal definition with

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
PrintDefinitions[Internal`PartitionRagged]
```

The reason for pointing this out is that answers which generate a list of positions and then use `Differences` to convert to sub-list lengths (for input to `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``) can be marginally improved by skipping the `Differences` and `Accumulate` steps.

Here's a modified version of LLlAMnYP's code. The compiled function outputs two lists, these are the start and end points for each sub-list in the original array. The main function just MapThreads `Take` over these lists.

```
fc = Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{a = Accumulate[data], i, n = Length[data], ref = 1.0, bag = Internal`Bag[{0}]},
    Do[If[a[[i]] >= ref, Internal`StuffBag[bag, i]; ref = a[[i]] + 1.0], {i, n - 1}];
    Internal`StuffBag[bag, n];
    {1 + Most@Internal`BagPart[bag, All], Rest@Internal`BagPart[bag, All]}]];

f0[data_] := Module[{p = fc@data}, MapThread[Take[data, {#1, #2}] &, p]]
```

In my tests this comes out a few percent faster than LLlAMnYP's. As with all the answers, the bottleneck is the unpacking of the original packed data into a ragged list.

Comment: Very nice observation. I was curious, why Accumulate isn't on the compilable functions' list.

Answer (score 6):

```
f[x_, y_] := Module[{new}, If[Total[new = Append[x, y]] >= 1, Sow[new]; {}, new]]
Reap[Fold[f, {}, dat]][[2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Borrowing heavily from other answers here, but I wanted to do as much as I could inside `Compile`. On my machine, this is a bit faster than LLIAMnYP's `main`:

```
runsComp = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}},
Block[{ans = ConstantArray[{0, 0}, Length@list + 1], t = 0., j = 1,
 len = Length[list]},
Do[(t += list[[i]]) <= 1 || (ans[[j + 1]] = {ans[[j, 2]] + 1, i}; 
  j++;t = 0), {i, len}
];

If[ans[[j, 2]] != len, ans[[j + 1]] = {ans[[j, 2]] + 1, len}; 
j++];
ans[[2 ;; j]]
], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];

runs[list_] := list[[#1 ;; #2]] & @@@ runsComp[list]
```

I'm on 10.0.2 so I don't have `RepeatedTiming`, but on my Macbook Pro I get

```
test = RandomReal[1, 1*^6];

main[test] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
runs[test] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.667418, 368209}
> {0.593660, 368209}
> ```

Comment: Not to be a sore loser, but using a C compiler makes a difference - I don't have one set up. What impresses me though, is that your roundabout implementation of `PartitionRagged` performs on par with the built-in. +1

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, Oh, I overlooked that you didn't compile to C actually! And it indeed makes a difference, to the point that a WVM version of my function is slower than yours. I guess I have just become too used to compiling to C without even trying WVM lately...

Comment: The question I'm taking home from today's thread, is "what is an efficient data structure for storing and creating ragged arrays?".``Internal`PartitionRagged`` is faster than any home-brewed functions, but still pretty slow. I tried linked lists, but they are also not compilable and `Bag` is, if I'm not mistaken essentially a linked list.