# Variable iterator in Do Loop (splitting a list)

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I have a list in Mathematica that looks like the following:

```
{{92,3},{23,3},{93,3},{63,2},{66,2},{24,4},{94,4},{27,4},{72,4},....}
```

The point is that the second number in each row dictates how many entries of that type there will be consecutively (3 consecutive "3" entries, 4 consecutive "4" entries, etc.)

My goal is to rearrange this list so that it looks like:

```
{{92,23,93},{63,66},{24,94,27,72},...}
```

so that I can plot the data with these numbers stacked on each other.

I am attempting to do this with the following module:

```
roundtrips[table_]:=Module[{newtable,numpeaks,i},
            Do[
              numpeaks=table[[i]][[2]];
              newtable[[i]]=Table[table[[i]],{i,i+numpeaks-1}],
              {i,1,Length[table], ???}]
               ]
```

What I would like to do is have the stepsize of the iterator vary based on what `numpeaks` is, so that it doesn't double or triple count entries. My first attempt was to put `numpeaks` in place of `???`, but Mathematica didn't like this. Is there a good way to do this, or an easier way to do what I'm trying to do?

---

*clarified in a comment:*

So for example, I would want:
   `{{34,2},{83,2},{24,2},{74,2}}`
to become
   `{{34,83},{24,72}}`

Comment: Does `Values@GroupBy[lst, Last -> First]` work? Or maybe `SplitBy[lst, Last][[All, All, 1]]` instead? Are the things elements to be grouped together always in order?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a job for `SplitBy` with some post-processing:

```
separate[lst:{{_, _Integer} ..}] :=
  Flatten[Partition[#, #[[1, 2]]] & /@ SplitBy[lst, Last], 1][[All, All, 1]]
```

Alternatively (and a touch faster),

```
separate[lst : {{_, _Integer} ..}] :=
  (Sequence @@ Partition[#, #[[1, 2]]] & /@ SplitBy[lst, Last])[[All, All, 1]]
```

Here is an explanation of the process:

Take as a sample list

```
lst = {{a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}, {d, 2}, {e, 2}, {f, 2}, {g, 2}, {h, 4}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}, {k, 4}};
```

Then

```
lst2 = SplitBy[lst, Last]
(* {{{a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}}, {{d, 2}, {e, 2}, {f, 2}, {g, 2}}, {{h, 4}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}, {k, 4}}} *)
```

We can see that the elements labeled `d`, `e`, `f`, and `g` have been improperly grouped. So we do some post-processing of these lists by `Partition`ing the sets by the number:

```
lst3 = Partition[#, #[[1, 2]]] & /@ lst2
(* { {{{a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}}},
     {{{d, 2}, {e, 2}}, {{f, 2}, {g, 2}}},
     {{{h, 4}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}, {k, 4}}}} *)
```

It's still not quite right, so we `Flatten` once:

```
lst4 = Flatten[lst3, 1]
(* {{{a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}}, {{d, 2}, {e, 2}}, {{f, 2}, {g, 2}}, {{h, 4}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}, {k, 4}}} *)
```

Finally, take only the first elements:

```
lst4[[All, All, 1]]
(* {{a, b, c}, {d, e}, {f, g}, {h, i, j, k}} *)
```

**Update 1**

Here is another version that is about 8 times slower than my other one, but it's cute because it does the `Split`ting in one go:

```
separate2[lst : {{_, _Integer} ..}] := 
  Module[{i = 1}, SplitBy[lst, If[2 #[[2]] - 1 > i++, 1, i = 0; 0] &]][[All, All, 1]]
```

---

Some basic timings. We generate a sample list:

```
SeedRandom[1]
lst = Flatten[Table[{RandomInteger[{1, #}], #}, {#}] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 7}, 3000], 1];
lst // Length
(* 11883 *)
```

and then

```
lst // separate; // AbsoluteTiming // First
lst // separate2; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.025516 *)
(* 0.083057 *)
```

**Update 2**

Here is a replacement-based approach using `Sow` and `Reap` that I feel is pretty clever, but it is *really* slow:

```
separate3[lst : {{_, _Integer} ..}] := 
  Last@Reap[
    lst //. {pat : Longest[PatternSequence[{_, n_Integer} ..]], b___}
      :> (Sow[Partition[{pat}[[All, 1]], n]]; {b})
   ]~Flatten~2
```

So don't try it on big lists! It scales terribly.

**Update 3**

Here's another solution, using recursion. It's much better than the replacement version, but still a lot significantly slower than the first two versions at large list sizes. Still, I like it:

```
Clear@func
func[{}] = {};
func[lst_List] := Module[{},
  Sow[Partition[lst[[;; #, 1]], #] &@lst[[1, 2]]];
  func[Drop[lst, lst[[1, 2]]]];
 ]
separate4[lst : {{_, _Integer} ..}] := 
  Block[{$RecursionLimit = 10000}, Last@Reap@func[lst]~Flatten~2]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Update:* After further consideration here is a method that I believe is both elegant and closer in spirit to your own code.  I am calling it `fn0` as I probably should have started with this.  Nevertheless I hope that you find the other methods I provide also of interest.

```
fn0[a_List] :=
  Module[{p = 1, n = Length @ a},
    Join @@ Table[a[[p++, 1]], {n}, {Boole[p < n]}, {a[[p + 1, 2]]}]
  ]
```

Using the same principle as [Partitioning a list when the cumulative sum exceeds 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105792/121):

```
fn1[a_List] :=
  Module[{i = a[[1, 2]]},
    Split[a, --i > 0 || (i = #2[[2]]) &][[All, All, 1]]
  ]
```

Using a method similar to [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7808#7808):

```
fn2[a_List] :=
  Inner[a[[# ;; #2, 1]] &, #[[;; -2]] + 1, #[[2 ;;]], List] & @ 
    NestWhileList[# + a[[# + 1, 2]] &, 0, Evaluate[Length[a] > #] &]
```

*And now using `Compile` for `NestWhileList` a la `partitionBy3`:*

```
fnRLE =
  Compile[{{aa, _Integer, 1}},
    With[{n = Length[aa]},
      NestWhileList[# + aa[[# + 1]] &, 0, n > # &]
    ]
  ];

fn2fast[a_List] :=
  Module[{a1, a2},
    {a1, a2} = List @@ (a\[Transpose]);  (* /q/28998/ *)
    Inner[a1[[# ;; #2]] &, #[[;; -2]] + 1, #[[2 ;;]], List] & @ fnRLE @ a2
  ]
```

A different method also using dynamic/ragged partitioning:

```
fn3[a_List] :=
  Internal`PartitionRagged[
    a[[All, 1]],
    ConstantArray[#[[1]], Length[#]/#[[1]]] & /@ Split @ a[[All, 2]] // Catenate
  ]
```

Test:

```
test = {{92, 3}, {23, 3}, {93, 3}, {63, 2}, {66, 2}, {24, 4},
 {94, 4}, {27, 4}, {72, 4}, {34, 2}, {83, 2}, {24, 2}, {74, 2}};

fn0[test]

% === fn1[test] === fn2[test] === fn2fast[test] === fn3[test]
```

> ```
> {{92, 23, 93}, {63, 66}, {24, 94, 27, 72}, {34, 83}, {24, 74}}
>
> True
> ```

### Benchmark

Here is a benchmark including march's methods.  I did not test `separate3` or `separate4` as he notes these as being slower.  I also omitted the argument testing from his functions to eliminate any overhead associated with it.

```
mkSample[m_Integer][n_Integer] := 
  Flatten[
    Table[{RandomInteger[{1, #}], #}, {#}] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, m}, n],
    1
  ] // Developer`ToPackedArray;

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

fns = {separate, separate2, fn0, fn1, fn2, fn2fast, fn3};

BenchmarkPlot[fns, mkSample[13], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image]

I don't know why BenchmarkPlot fits `fn2fast` as $n*log(n)$ as all these functions appear to be linear time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this with some fake data generated to test it.

```
list=Join@@Table[{{RandomInteger[{1,20}],2},{RandomInteger[{1,20}],2}}, {2000}];
Reap[
  While[list != {},
    Sow[Map[First, Take[list, list[[1, 2]]]]];
    list = Drop[list, list[[1, 2]]]]
][[2, 1]]
```

Please check this carefully to make certain that it works correctly on your real data.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, way easier than I was trying to make it.

Comment: Wait sorry, this doesn't work--I think it only works for the entries that are separated by distinct numbers if that makes sense? So for example, I would want:
   `{{34,2,},{83,2},{24,2},{74,2}}`
to become
   `{{34,83},{24,72}}`

Comment: @naomig: does it mean that an entry like: {{23,3},{72.3},{17,2}} is not valid and should trigger an error message ?

Comment: @ChristianNéel That's correct, but there won't be any entries like that in my data set.

Comment: wow, that does take a long time. My list is thousands of entries long :)